# Play Store Publishing API "Open Testing"

Tags: android, automation, continuous-integration, google-play

I am trying to publish my different app versions to the Play Store in an automated fashion. I have Fastlane setup and have no issue getting the `Production`, `Closed Testing - Alpha`, `Closed Testing - Beta` and `Internal` tracks to publish. However, I am unable to publish to the `Open Testing` track because there seems to be no option for it in Fastlane or Google Play (even according to their docs: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks).

Has anyone solved this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify *any* `track` name you want.

The tracks listed in the documentation point to the default set that all apps should have. You can create new tracks and use them in your automation.

I created an Open Beta Track and renamed it to `open_beta`. Then, I set the `track` parameter in the `supply` lane to `open_beta`. That's it! The artifact was successfully uploaded to the new Open Beta Track.

```rb
supply(track: 'open_beta', rollout: 0.2)
```

The documentation doesn't really point out this possibility. I found it possible by accident when reading through the [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) documentation, where they say the following:

> `track` is the target stage for an artifact, i.e. `internal`/`alpha`/`beta`/`production` or **any custom track**